# How to include events: {} property of a custom highchart data into highcharts-vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, highcharts

vue to build graps. i am usually passing my JSON into the :options of the  tag like

Now i am trying to build a custom chart using the renderer and ren.path().attr().add() functions. Since this properties uses load function() inside the chart options i cant able to convert this into a JSON file.

THE CUSTOM CHART VALUE:

```
{
chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    borderWidth: 1,
    events: {
        load: function () {
            var ren = this.renderer,
                colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
                rightArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 10, 0, 'L', 5, 5, 'M', 10, 0, 'L', 5, -5];
    ren.path(['M', 50, 100, 'L', 550, 100])
                .attr({
                'stroke-width': 3,
                                stroke: 'black',
                                dashstyle: 'solid'
                })
                .add();

  ren.text('0%', 50 , 150).add();
  ren.text('Peer Group 1', 50, 50).add();
  ren.text('20%', 150 , 150).add();
  ren.text('Peer Group 2', 150, 50).add();
  ren.text('40%', 250 , 150).add();
  ren.text('Peer Group 3', 250, 50).add();
  ren.text('60%', 350 , 150).add();
  ren.text('Peer Group 4', 350, 50).add();
  ren.text('80%', 450 , 150).add();
  ren.text('Peer Group 5', 450, 50).add();
  ren.text('100%', 550 , 150).add();

   ren.path(['M', 100, 80, 'L', 100, 120])
     .attr({'stroke-width': 3,stroke: 'black',dashstyle: 'solid'}).add();
   ren.path(['M', 200, 80, 'L', 200, 120])
     .attr({'stroke-width': 3,stroke: 'black',dashstyle: 'solid'}).add();
   ren.path(['M', 300, 80, 'L', 300, 120])
     .attr({'stroke-width': 3,stroke: 'black',dashstyle: 'solid'}).add();
   ren.path(['M', 400, 80, 'L', 400, 120])
     .attr({'stroke-width': 3,stroke: 'black',dashstyle: 'solid'}).add();
   ren.path(['M', 500, 80, 'L', 500, 120])
     .attr({'stroke-width': 3,stroke: 'black',dashstyle: 'solid'}).add();  


    ren.circle(150, 100, 9).attr({fill: '#0000FF',
            stroke: 'black','stroke-width': 0}).add();
 ren.text('20%', 140, 70).css({color: '#0000FF'}) .add();

        }
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts export server overview',
    style: {
        color: 'black'
    }
}

}
```

See this https://jsfiddle.net/87ng9v1z/ the JSON is working fine. i always use the same type of working json and parse it into the  tag as show above.

Am i missing something ?
Is there an another way to load this type of data into the highcharts or how to convert this data into the JSON format.

Comment: Could you be more precise? What exactly do you want to convert into JSON format?

Comment: If you can see the above JSON, it has load function() inside events. i need to know how to pass that events object into the <highchart  :options="HERE"/>. i dont know why but it is not loading the datas if i do like this. i want to know is this the right way to do this or not

Comment: Check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/9y236z4m5y. Yes, it is the correct approach.

Comment: thanks for the demo. is there a way to include the events: {} property

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: for other type of charts i simply pass the JSON into the options in the <highcharts> tag and it will load the chart. but if i try to pass the above JSON it is not generating the chart, so i thought this would happen because of the load function in the event: {}

Comment: The load function should not be this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who ran to the same problem,
I accomplished the above by using the :callback to call the load function

```
<highcharts ref="highcharts" :options="data" :callback="load" ></highcharts>
```